# list every date with date name in php or javascript

Tags: php, date, echo

is there a way to list every date and date name in php or javascript?
Example

1. jan 1 Wednesday
2. jan 2 Thursday
3. jan 3 Friday

etc etc, if someone can spread some light on if and how to do this i would appreciate it. thank you.

Comment: Every date from which dates? It's definitively possible with a `for` loop and a DateTime object.

Comment: from the current year.

Comment: So list every date that of that year.

Comment: Okay, that's easy - set the date to the first of the year, and create a loop where you add 1 day. Once the year changes, break the loop

Comment: thats a brilliant idea. ! ill give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod).

```
$start = new DateTime('1/1'); // first day of the current year
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // iterate 1 day at a time
$end = new DateTime('1/1 next year'); // stop when we get to first day of next year
// All of these periods are equivalent.
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

// By iterating over the DatePeriod object, all of the
// recurring dates within that period are printed.
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
}
```

This will give you every day of the current year.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$date = "2019-12-31";

do {
    $date = date("M d l", strtotime($date . "+ 1 day"));
    echo $date . "<br>" ;
}while(strtotime($date) != strtotime("2020-12-31"));
```

Output:

```
Jan 01 Wednesday
Jan 02 Thursday
Jan 03 Friday
Jan 04 Saturday
.
.
.
Dec 31 Thursday
```

This code starts at Jan 1st and prints out all dates in the format of `Month Day Weekday` and iterates through the whole year until December 31st.